# AngryIP says the Raspberry pi is a dead host

Tags: ssh

I have Raspberry PI model 3.  I am using VNC to access the Pi over Ethernet.

Everything was working perfectly fine, until one time I scanned for alive host using Angry IP scanner. It shows the the IP of my Pi, and that it is dead. Therefore, I can not connect to the PI

I am using windows 10 and just want the Raspberry Pi to be an alive host.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just reboot it?

Comment: i tried, it didnt work. I guess the problem is from Windows/Network stuff not from the Raspberry pi side

Comment: Not necessarily.  You will probably need a monitor and keyboard to investigate the problem.

Comment: alright i connected the pi to a monitor now and got it working but with no internet connection "same problem" , would you please tell me what should i do now?

Comment: Can you ping to or from the PI. Could you update your question with the results of `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and `ifconfig -a`

Comment: Check your configuration: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37920/5538

Answer (score 1):

For others who are still stuck:
Try doing this:
Step1: Go to your wifi and then open Network and internet settings.
[image]

Step2: After that go to change adapter options.(You can directly search for this after opening the control panel as well, I am just speaking about the way I used to proceed).
[image]

Step 3: Open WiFi and then click on properties.
Step 4: There you will find two tabs one networking and sharing, go to sharing and chances are either:
i. sharing is marked (i.e. the bridge between ethernet and WiFi already exists)
or 
ii. it's unmarked. 
If it's case ii. select the ethernet port to connect to and mark it as allow sharing of networks. save this setting and you are good to go.

If its case i. unmark the option allow sharing save the settings and again open the same wifi tab and perform the above steps and continue as mentioned for case ii.
This happens when you leave your pi and keep the bridge unoperated for long go. The way in which I explained kinda refreshes and re-establishes the connection between the pi and the system.
Happy rasping!

Answer (score 0):

do you use the virtual machine? check the ip address of the latter.
If not, just delete the DNS cache of your laptop by using this command (ipconfig /flushdns)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT :
i made a bridge connection between the WIFI and the Ethernet 
thus, i was able to find the raspberry pi as an alive host from the IP scanner

Comment: You should explain the exact steps you took to do this.